# how to fetch key and values object matched with requesURI

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var object1 = [ { 
      "key" : "/create", 
      "value" : "synch_consent,synch_p2p" 
    }, { 
      "key" : "/update", 
      "value" : "synch_consent,synch_basic" 
    } ] 
var requestURI = "/create"
```

have to compare requestURI with object and matched object key and values

have to get

```
output: { 
      "key" : "/create", 
      "value" : "synch_consent,synch_p2p" 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var object1 = [ { "key" : "/create", "value" : "synch_consent,synch_p2p" }, { "key" : "/update", "value" : "synch_consent,synch_basic" } ] 
var requestURI = "/create"
---
{ "output": (object1 filter ((item, index) -> item.key == requestURI))[0] }
```

This will get the first one that matches, or null if nothing is found.